# How to put everyone except myself into adventure mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I use a command block to turn everyone (except myself) into adventure mode (gamemode 2)? Any command which does this would be awesome.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: Have you tried any commands yourself?

Comment: no i couldnt find any like except player name command

Comment: Is there a way to use radius more than?

Comment: Ex. /gamemode 2 @a[LeastRadius=3]

Answer (score 7):

Try using

```
/gamemode adventure @a[name=!<player>]
```

What this exactly does is:
`/gamemode adventure` - Sets gamemode to adventure.

`@a[name=!<player>]` - Targets all players, except the name of the player specified there. The `!` means "except".

If your Minecraft name for example was MrLuca, then the command would be:

```
/gamemode adventure @a[name=!MrLuca]
```

Comment: +1 This answer is better than mine, to be honest. My answer doesn't work with command blocks, and has some possible pitfalls.

Comment: Do be aware that Minecraft development is trying to move away from numerical IDs. It would be preferable to use "adventure" instead of "2" (and the same would go for the `m` selector parameter, which has been updated in 1.9 to accept the name ID; `@a[m=adventure]`).

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode adventure @a[name=!<player>]`; The "move away from numerical IDs" finally finished in 1.13

Answer (score 4):

```
/gamemode adventure @a[rm=1]
```

Should do the trick. The `rm` tag means everyone *outside* of the given radius. Since you will most probably be the only one that close to yourself, this should work. If not, just move to a different place.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect, the player argument comes after the gamemode.

Comment: @Skylinerw Didn't realize that! Sorry! Fixed it know. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: This would be good if you run /execute on yourself (so you are the center of execution, not the commandblock), but otherwise it is not usable a lot.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/gamemode adventure @a[distance=1..]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `/gamemode a @a[name=!Your_name_here]`

Comment: Can you add more to your answer like your source and how this works.